# creating snapshot for mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb, snapshot

I am trying to create snapshot for mongodb on centos 6.6.

```
root@ ~]# lvscan
File descriptor 12 (pipe:[23409]) leaked on lvscan invocation. Parent   
PID 3579: /bin/bash
File descriptor 13 (pipe:[23409]) leaked on lvscan invocation. Parent   
PID 3579: /bin/bash
ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_test/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_test/lv_home' [411.49 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_test/lv_swap' [3.78 GiB] inherit
```

my mongodb data is in folder /home/db/mongodata. Command I need to run is

```
lvcreate -s -n mysnapshot -L450G /dev/mapper/vg_test-lv_home.
```

But this will take snapshot of whole volume.

1. I want snapshot of only /home/db/mongodata. Is it possible?
2. Also how to create this snapshot on another server directly rather than creating the snapshot on same machine and copying it to another server.
   Created same at https://serverfault.com/questions/679299/creating-snapshot-for-mongodb

I am not looking for mongodb backup using mongodump and mongorestore. I have a SAN where mongodb is writting data e.g /home/db/mongodata (around 5-15 TB). I want snapshot of this folder only.